# Dealing with changing iOS keyboard layout upon rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-app-extension

I have two slightly different layouts for my keyboard based on the orientation of the device.  When I load up the keyboard at first, it looks fine.  Here's the portrait version:

[image: Portrait Keyboard]

The initial constraint setup occurs within -viewDidLoad (of the UIInputViewController subclass)

```
portraitConstraints = [self constraintsForOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
landscapeConstraints = [self constraintsForOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];

[self.view addConstraints:portraitConstraints];
[self.view addConstraints:landscapeConstraints];

if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width < [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height) {
    [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:landscapeConstraints];
} else {
    [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:portraitConstraints];
}
```

This part works, as it loads correctly regardless of initial orientation.  However, once I rotate the device, everything goes wrong.

[image: Wrong]

And then back to portrait:

[image: Wrong]

For reference, the proper landscape version looks like this:

[image: Landscape]

I update the constraints in -updateViewConstraints as follows:

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints {
    if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width < [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height) {
        [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:landscapeConstraints];
        [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:portraitConstraints];
    } else {
        [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:portraitConstraints];
        [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:landscapeConstraints];
    }

    [super updateViewConstraints];
}
```

It seems like after the view changes it suddenly takes up more than full screen instead of just the keyboard area.  Any ideas how I can fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: not sure but it might be case of autlayout , i once stucked with curdish keyboard design so i use autolayout , it may help

Comment: I don't think it's the best idea to compare screen width against height. Instead, try accessing the status bar orientation, like this `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]. Or you could try to get the orientation of the device like this '[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]`.

Comment: Also, it looks to me like your constraints are to have the "0x" button, the space button, and the return button be of fixed width in portrait and the globe takes up the rest. Then, I would guess you have aspect ratios applied, which would make sense of how the first "wrong" keyboard looks.

Comment: @SKT Are you recommending I use or don't use autolayout?  I'm not sure what the default is outside of IB.

Comment: @mbm29414 I'm using width/height comparison because because you can't check UIDevice orientation within an app extension, and statusBarOrientation sometimes return an unknown response when the device is laying flat due to it using accelerometer.  But I've put NSLogs inside my current way of doing it and it works fine - always prints out the correct orientation when it changes.

Comment: @NickEntin Ah. Didn't notice the app-extension tag. Gotcha. Still, the second image (the first "bad" one) looks about like I'd expect if the device is in landscape but you're setting up the portrait constraints. At least, based upon how I'm guessing your constraints are configured. Care to share the constraint code?

Comment: @mbm29414 Here you go: http://pastebin.com/j240S74A  Bit of a crazy method.  Tried to comment everything to explain what goes where.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68445/discussion-between-mbm29414-and-nickentin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appeared to be related to somehow implicitly overriding the height of the view that contained the keyboard. Although I didn't see anything that would force a resizing of the container view, explicitly setting the height of the container view got back to good, reproducible results.

I got the idea of manually constraining the keyboard's height from [Apple's App Extension Programming Guide: Custom Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW11).

Specifically, the relevant information was this:

> You can adjust the height of your custom keyboard’s primary view using Auto Layout. By default, a custom keyboard is sized to match the system keyboard, according to screen size and device orientation. A custom keyboard’s width is always set by the system to equal the current screen width. To adjust a custom keyboard’s height, change its primary view's height constraint.
>
> The following code lines show how you might define and add such a constraint:

```
CGFloat _expandedHeight = 500;
NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraint = 
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.view 
                             attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight 
                             relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                toItem: nil 
                             attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute 
                            multiplier: 0.0 
                              constant: _expandedHeight];
[self.view addConstraint: _heightConstraint];
```

> **NOTE**
>
> In iOS 8.0, you can adjust a custom keyboard’s height any time after its primary view initially draws on screen.

Here is the important method in a template answer based on this information:

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints {
    if (self.keyboardHeightConstraint == nil) {
        // Just starting with SOME value for the height
        self.keyboardHeightConstraint =
        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                        toItem:nil
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                    multiplier:0.0f
                                      constant:500.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:self.keyboardHeightConstraint];
    }
    // Obviously, these values will be changed based on device AND orientation
    // These are bogus values...
    if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width < [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height) {
        self.keyboardHeightConstraint.constant  = 300.0f;
        [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:self.landscapeConstraints];
        [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:self.portraitConstraints];
    } else {
        self.keyboardHeightConstraint.constant  = 400.0f;
        [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:self.portraitConstraints];
        [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:self.landscapeConstraints];
    }
    [super updateViewConstraints];
}
```